# Entity Framework - restrict users access / inject business rules

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know of any way to insert in business validation rules within entity frmework?
Ideally I want to use dynamicData across some portions of a EF model, and then handle securing access with the EF model itself.

For example, if looking at orders, I want to add in a rule that customers can only view their own companys orders.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

We do it with the [Service](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) and [Repository](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) patterns. There's [a basic example here](http://www.manning.com/seemann/MEAP_Seemann_01.pdf) [PDF]. Regading Dynamic Data, I strongly suggest binding to view models, not entities.

Comment: Yes, with EF4 planning to only expose POCO via repository pattern, and probably use a domain service to fully restrict / control.

For dynamic data though without using the futures build, I need a work around.  Do you have any examples of mapping to view models rather than entities - not come across that approach as the scaffolding seems to be bypassing any layering or intercepts I have tried (ie http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFPocoAdapter)

Comment: I use MVC 2 Dynamic Templated views rather than Dynamic Data *per se.* It's the same technology, but *much* more flexible.